# Barcode generation in ofbiz

Tags: barcode, freemarker, ofbiz

I am trying to generate Barcodes in ofbiz, i got some samples to generate barcodes in pdf using fo.ftl files (with barcode4j). But my actual requirement is to show the barcode in screen itself, using either with forms or .ftl which ever is possible.

I tried different options to generate, but i did not get solution.

Please reply my post, if anybody have idea on this issue.

Thanks,
Chandra K

Answer (score 1):

you should take a look at http://barcode4j.sourceforge.net/ and the creating barcodes section.
you can't just display barcodes in OFBiz, and the only way is to use pdf and fo.ftl. Displaying on the web page will demand a new implementation, and you are welcome to contribute !

Cheers,